# Current LEGO Digital Designer download is missing a lot of parts

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software, ldd

The current LDD download is missing a lot of bricks that were in version 1.3.11 before.

Such as, but not limited to:
EV3 motors, sensors and the main EV3 brick.

Does anyone have a solution/download with all the 1.3.11 bricks?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately LDD has been actively deprecated for quite a number of years and LEGO officially noted they would not be updating the parts set and would, in fact, be removing some parts quite a few years ago.

The only solution is to use one of the alternatives such as any of the options that use [the LDraw libraries](https://www.ldraw.org/downloads-2/third-party-software.html). One of the more popular right now (for good reason IHO) is [Stud.io](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page), which as of the completion of the BrickLink acquisition will be owned by TLG.

Comment: This is compounded by the fact that apparently 4.3.12 (which identifies in app as 4.3.11) does indeed appear to have removed a number of elements :(